# Prove that $13$ divides the number ${}^910 + 23$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that the number $13$ divides the number $\large \left( 10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10}}}}}}}} + 23\right)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$K\equiv 10^{10^{\ldots}}\pmod{13}$$

By [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) we have:

$$K\equiv 10^{10^{\ldots}\pmod{12}}\equiv 10^{(-2)^{\ldots}\pmod{12}}\pmod{13}$$

But $(-2)^k\equiv 4\pmod{12}, \forall k\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 2}$.

Hence

$$K\equiv 10^{4}\equiv 3^4\equiv 27\cdot 3\equiv 3\equiv -23\pmod{13}\ \ \ \square$$

Comment: Nice. And in fact the period of $10  \bmod 13$ is $6$, and $4^n \equiv 4 \bmod 6$ for all positive $n$.

Comment: @user314: but how can i demonstrate/prove this step in addition.$(-2)^k\equiv 4\pmod{12}, \forall k\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 2}$

Comment: @TAKITAKI $(-2)^2\equiv 4\pmod{12}$ and $(-2)^h\equiv 4\pmod{12}\implies (-2)^{h+1}\equiv 4\cdot (-2)\equiv -8\equiv 4\pmod{12}$ so by induction the fact follows.